# How to use LIMIT to sample rows dynamically

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table as follows:

| SampleReq | Group | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | _001 |
| 2 | 1 | _002 |
| 2 | 1 | _003 |
| 1 | 2 | _004 |
| 1 | 2 | _005 |
| 1 | 2 | _006 |

I want my query to IDs based on the column SampleReq, resulting in the following output:

| Group | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | _001 |
| 1 | _003 |
| 2 | _006 |

The query should pick any 2 IDs from group 1, any 1 IDs from group 2 and so on (depending on the column SampleReq).

I tried the query using LIMIT, but this gives me an error saying column names cannot be parsed to a limit.

```sql
SELECT Group, ID
FROM Table
LIMIT SampleReq
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using Azure databricks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Databricks is only an analytics platform, not a database itself. So what type of database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by samplereq order by random()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2 and id = 1 or
      seqnum <= 1 and id = 2;
```